# How to reach the factory methods of the Internal members of Aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

According to DDD we should not reference the internal members of an aggregate from outside the aggregate boundaries, but in this way how would I create an object of some internal entity so I can use it in creating the an object of Aggregate root entity?

For example:

I have an aggregate root Document and internal member of the aggregate root called Document and in order to create a Document object I have to call the factory method of it, but how would I associate a Page with the created Document during creating the Document? Because we can't call the factory method of the internal member from outside the aggregate boundaries consider we have the following code in a service layer ,
P.S: This is wrong code I think

`var page=Page.CreatePage(param1,param2...etc);
var document=Document.CreateDocument(page);`

It's wrong because we shouldn't access CreatePage from outside the aggregate boundaries so how to solve this problem about how to create internal members of an aggregate root when we want to create aggregate root entity?

Comment: Are you sure Document is the AR?? What is the relationship between a document and a page? Can a document exist without a page? What are the invariants you need to maintain? How are pages exposed through the document? What other behaviour does a document have?

Comment: Document with multiple pages .... like consider Passport is a document and each page of it is the pages
and relationship is one to many ... invariants like to not add pages to the document in the right sequence ... there are a lot of other behaviour we may have, it's just for example ,

Answer (score 4):

If `Page` is an entity then you shouldn't be creating it outside its aggregate root because that would break encapsulation.

For instance, if a `Document` cannot contain multiple pages with the same title you could violate the invariant by having a direct access to a `Page` object.

For instance,

```
var page1 = new Page('some title');
var page2 = new Page('some other title');
var document = new Document([page1, page2]);
page2.changeTitle('some title'); //this breaks the invariant
```

For that reason you should treat internal entities as implementation details of aggregate roots and avoid exposing them to the outside world.

You could use value objects instead to pass page information to a document.

For example, in the following `Page` is a **Value Object**. The `Document` aggregate will create internal `Document.Page` entities from the `Page` values.

```
var page1 = new Page('some title');
var document = new Document([page1]); //Document.Page entities are created internally

var page2 = new Page('some other title');
document.addPage(page2);
```

Comment: Excellent point, didn't consider changing the object after it had been passed to Document

Comment: thanks for your answer, but  according to DDD i can't create an object of Page entity outside of aggregate , so, how would i create a Document and associate pages with it?! because we can't do the following `var page=Page.CreatePage(some params) and then pass this page to Document.CreateDocument(page)`
okay, in this way i can be sure that the invariants are not violated , but my whole problem is about calling the factory method of page outside of the aggregate, there should be some way for example as following :`Document.AddPage(parameters for Page entity) ` 
is it good practice like this ?

Comment: @SalihKarabilo Did you read my answer? In the second example `Page` is a value object, not an entity. The `Document` will then create `Document.Page` entities internally based on the `Page` values it received.

Comment: thanks, Ofcourse i've read it, but i don't want Page to be as a value Object, it's an entity
is it possible that there's no solution for not calling internal "Entity" member factory from outside the aggregate ?

Comment: Page doesn't have to be a ValueObject, it can be, more generically, a DTO, a simple object that carries information to pass to the aggregate, so that the aggregate can use it to create an entity (or more than one, it doesn't have to be one to one). Also, I don't see any problem in just passing the parameters inline in the aggregate method, without using a DTO if it's only a few.